# Getting multiple select when reloading the page using angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have one issue.I am using Angular.js `ui-router` for displaying the nested views.In my case i have one parent menu and it has some sub menus. Let me to explain my code below.

> dashboard.html:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active" ><a ui-sref="dashboard">Home</a></li>
<li  ui-sref-active="active">
<a ui-sref=".res.userrole">Resource Management</a>
</li>
```

Here `Resource Management` is my parent menu and its sub menus are given below.

> res.html:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.userrole" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add User Role</tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <!--<tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.course" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add Course</tab-heading>
    </tab>-->
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.class" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add Class</tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.section" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add Section</tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.session" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add Session</tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab ui-sref="dashboard.res.unit" ui-sref-active="active">
      <tab-heading>Add Unit</tab-heading>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
  <div ui-view></div>
```

> Loginroute.js:

```
.state('dashboard.res', {
        url: '/res',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/res.html',
        controller: 'resController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.userrole', {
        url: '/userrole',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/userrole.html',
        controller: 'resourceuserroleController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.class', {
        url: '/class',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/class.html',
        controller: 'resourceclassController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.section', {
        url: '/section',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/section.html',
        controller: 'resourcesectionController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.session', {
        url: '/session',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/session.html',
        controller: 'resourceSessionController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.res.unit', {
        url: '/unit',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/unit.html',
        controller: 'resourceunitController'
    })
```

Here my problem is when i am reloading any page of the above sub menu the first sub menu('i.e-Add User Role')  is getting active class along with the refreshing sub menu page.So at a time i am getting two sub menu are active.Here i need if user is reloading any sub menu page that sub menu title will remain active.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: hi,  please consider post a plunk,  it will great helpful.

Comment: Ok,give me some time.I am preparing.

Comment: @lessisawesome :HI,it was too diffucult to add all code i made for two submenu(`i.e-Add User Role,Add class`).My requirement is in my post.please take [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oABlXnrMxeNK0JNPnVR6?p=preview) link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a idea using $state.includes().

e.g:

```
if state is /home/:id, Home tab will be activated.

if state is /home/sub/:id, Home and Home sub tabs will be activated
```

code example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('home')}" class="active"><a ui-sref="home" href="/">Home</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('home.sub')}" ><a ui-sref="home.sub" href="/">Home sub</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('reports')}" ><a ui-sref="reports" href="/admin/reports">Reports</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('users')}" ><a ui-sref="users" href="/admin/users">Users</a></li>            
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('groups')}" ><a ui-sref="groups" href="/admin/groups">Groups</a></li>
```

Hope this may help to your case.

Comment: I am not getting your comment.I have the issue about the child menu.

Comment: @subhra, for my understanding, you want to active the child menu and its parent menu, is that ?

Comment: @ lessisawesome: exactly.

Comment: @ lessisawesome: I have added my code in post can you update your answer there.